# OAuth Using UIWebView iOS

Tags: ios, swift, oauth

I would want to know how can I make user login `OAuth` via a `UIWebView` instead of `Safari` browser.

I've implemented `Twitter` `OAuth` with Deployd as backend, after making login with `Twitter` it redirects to my API url for a `POST` request and get stuck. It's not redirecting back to the application.

So any approach or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you're not using the [Fabric SDK](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/fabric/index.html)? It makes it really easy to login a user via Twitter and it checks automatically if an account is set up in the System Settings. If there isn't one, it'll present the OAuth login option. In this way your user doesn't have to leave your app which is great.

Comment: after clicking 'authorize' app is getting stuck to the next url I'm calling - http://i.stack.imgur.com/5i2MQ.png

Comment: is there a method for get called when a URL request is done